# simulating a REAL submit from within javascript (setting what element causes the submit, programatically)

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I need to be able to simulate a *REAL* submit post form within javascript.

the reason is simple, I am not posting from the original form but from a dynamic copy built on submit.  I cannot change how the form is built as this is not a form handler but a framework built around any other person`s forms.  I am using jquery in this app and chrome is the target browser (though a solution in FF would also be cool, if its different).

Please don't suggest to use other types of input or use hidden fields, really, I know all about this.

so, when generating a form manually and calling form.submit()  is there a property or attribute I can set (or method I can call) within the form which will allow it to generate a proper submit-type post?

Comment: wtf, its been negatively ranked? could someone tell me why?

Comment: I've been searching for 3 days for a solution to this and haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 0):

form.submit() does a submit. What you probably mean is that you need to include all of the other infrastructure required by a server-side framework. In that case, you need to tell us what framework.

Comment: form.submit() doesn't add the submit button information (in this case multiple image submits).  The server needs to know which one was clicked, so I need to set it up within the dynamic form created.

Comment: note, from the javascript, I know which was clicked on, I just need to know how I can set that up within the new form I create before using form.submit() on it.